# Lexicographic ordering in expl3

Tags: expl3, sorting

Is there a function in expl3 which detects lexicographic (alphabetic) ordering, e.g. returns TRUE for `"Abel" precedes "able"`? Browsing through the `interface3` document suggests there is not. If there were it would save me the trouble of writing a `base 26` conversion (and which would only be good for short words anyway).

Comment: You can just use `\pdfstrcmp{Abel}{abel}`, which yields `-1`. That is "Abel" < "abel". And, it's expandable!

Comment: Looks promising! Where can I read up on `\pdfstrcmp`?

Comment: Section **8.15 Strings** (p 39) of the [pdfTeX users manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf).

Comment: @Werner I would like to mark your input as the answer, but the site does not provide me with a click.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At present there are no built-in methods for such textual comparisons (there are generic sorting wrappers but one has to supply the comparison code). The reason for this is that sorting is complex: rules are language-specific and need a lot of Unicode data.

For simple sorting in English one can use the fact that the character codes for letters are 'correctly' ordered. This can be exploited using the `\pdfstrcmp` primitive in pdfTeX, which is accessible using a documented-but-internal function in `expl3` (*i.e.* we might change the name here!). This might lead to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \printsorted { m }
  { \rn_sort:n {#1} }
\clist_new:N \l__rn_sort_clist
\cs_new_protected:Npn \rn_sort:n #1
  {
    \group_begin:
      \clist_set:Nn \l__rn_sort_clist {#1}
      \clist_sort:Nn \l__rn_sort_clist
        {
          \int_compare:nNnTF { \__str_if_eq:nn {##1} {##2} } < 0
            { \sort_return_same: }
            { \sort_return_swapped: }
        }
      \clist_use:Nn \l__rn_sort_clist { , }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\printsorted{Abel, abel}
\printsorted{abel, Abel}
\printsorted{abel,Bee}
\end{document}
```

Notice that as we are using only character codes we end up with all strings starting with a capital before those starting with a lower case letter: one could make a more sophisticated version with a two-part sort to deal with this.

---

The reason that `\__str_if_eq:nn` is internal is that it's basically direct access to `\pdfstrcmp` but set up to work with pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX and e-(u)pTeX. In particular, the team only ever use this to test for equality, not for ordering, precisely because of the issues related to language and case.

Answer (score 7):

Somthing similar can be achieved using LuaTeX.  Sorting is probably much faster in Lua.

To parse the comma list I use `utilities.parsers.settings_to_array` from ConTeXt.  To do so, I have to import the necessary ConTeXt core files.

As one can see from the example, the sorting is not Unicode aware.  However, Lua’s `table.sort` receives two arguments, namely the table to be sorted and an optional sorting function.  Here one could implement an [own sorting function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167886) which does the correct sorting depending on the language.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua{ % Use ConTeXt libraries
dofile(kpse.find_file("l-lpeg.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-sto.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-prs.lua"))
}

\directlua{
function printsorted(keywords)
    local input = utilities.parsers.settings_to_array(keywords)
    table.sort(input)
    tex.sprint(table.concat(input,", "))
end
}

\newcommand\printsorted[1]{%
  \directlua{printsorted(\unexpanded{[==[#1]==]})}}

\begin{document}
\printsorted{Übermut, Angst, Okay, ungenau, Ökonom, Ärger}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that LuaTeX is not 'natively' Unicode nor does it have any built-in libraries for locale-based sorting (_cf._ Perl for example)

Comment: @JosephWright Noted + example added.

Comment: @HenriMenke An interesting alternative, thanks, but I am steering clear of LuaTex for the time being and will therefore run with `expl3` and `l3sort`. `LuaTex` is certainly on my agenda, in this context and a number of others. Also, speed will be an important consideration.